Problem with organizing models and forms in Django
I need a good tip, how can i create registration form fro this two models:
class Adress(models.Model):
    """
    Abstract model for users and organizations adresses
    """
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    house_number = models.IntegerField()
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Adress"
        verbose_name_plural = "Adresses"

And Patient model:

class Patient(DiaScreenUser):
    """
    Choices for diabet type options
    """
    FIRST_TYPE = '1'
    SECOND_TYPE = '2'
    NULL_TYPE = 'null'
    DIABETES_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (FIRST_TYPE, '1 тип'),
        (SECOND_TYPE, '2 тип'),
        (NULL_TYPE, 'відсутній'),
    )

    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    body_mass_index = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    connect_to_doctor_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    diabet_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=DIABETES_TYPE_CHOICES, default=NULL_TYPE)
    is_oninsuline = models.BooleanField(db_index=True)
    doctor_id = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    adress_id = models.ForeignKey(Adress, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, db_index=True, null=True)

I need a registration form in which patient could input his personal info AND adress info ( BUT i cant understand how it works when i have a foreign key in my patient model ). Thanks for any advices!
I tried create something like that, but in this case i cannot understand how to link adress to a patient
class AdressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Adress
        fields = ["country","city"]
        
class PatientForm(ModelForm):
    
    adress_form = AdressForm()
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "phone_number",
        ]


Try address_id__country and address_id__city in your ModelForm fields attr

You mean in PatientForm Meta class?

Yes you need to access the FK attributes

Nope( It doesnt work, unknown field specified for Patient

Here are some pointers, using a class-based view. The general idea is: create a form for Patient, with some extra fields corresponding to Adress, then create both objects from this form in the view.
1. The form
Augment your PatientForm by specifying more form fields. You want one form field per necessary field for Adress model. You can specify things like, is the field required for sending the form, how long should a string be... Check the docs
from django import forms
from ..models import Patient

class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm) :
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = [
            "username",
            "email",
            "phone_number",
            # any other field you need from Patient model
        ]

    # then add the fields you need to create Adress model

    country = forms.CharField(label="Country", required=False)
    city = forms.CharField(label="City", required=False)
    street = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    house_number = forms.IntegerField()
    postal_code = forms.CharField()

2. The view
Your form is paired with a view, where you can do the work of creating the Adress, saving it in your DB, then using it to create your Patient :
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from ..forms import PatientForm
from ..models import Patient, Adress

class PatientFormView(CreateView):
    model = Patient
    form_class = PatientForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("home")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        adress = Adress(
            country = form.cleaned_data["country"],
            city = form.cleaned_data["city"],
            street = form.cleaned_data["street"],
            house_number = form.cleaned_data["house_number"],
            postal_code = form.cleaned_data["postal_code"]
        )
        adress.save()

        self.object = Patient(
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"],
            email = form.cleaned_data["email"],
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data["phone_number"]
            ...
            adress = adress
        )
        self.object.save()

        return redirect(self.get_success_url())

